# select last record entered each day summed over a period of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have the below query which returns the records entered each day for a given date range (from `@startDate` to `@EndDate`).

This is where I am stuck: I want to get the last records entered each day each pivoted column, so I can have a true sum of all final records entered between the Start and end dates.

Can anyone provide some guidance please? I tried the MAX(TransDate) but it doesn't work with this particular pivot setting. here is a picture of the resulting dataset [image]

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '06/21/2021',
        @EndDate DATE = '06/27/2021'
    
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         h.StoreId, d.category, d.Qty, d.transdate
     FROM   
         tblHeader h 
     INNER JOIN 
         tblDetail d ON h.Storeid = d.Storeid 
                     AND h.DonationId = d.DonationId
     WHERE 
         d.TransDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AS DnrCat 
PIVOT 
    (SUM(Qty) 
        FOR Category IN ([Daily Donors], 
                         [Textiles Hung], 
                         [Gaylord/Bulk IN],
                         [Gaylord/Bulk OUT], 
    ) AS Pvt
```

Comment: (1) I don't see how that query is doing what you describe.  (2) Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: *"and I can't make edits now"* do you mean to your post? Yes you can, just use the [edit] feature.